# Единственное или множественное число? (4)

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, единственное-множественное-число, деловой-язык

*Опекун или иное лицо, осуществляющ**ие** (**-ее**) управление денежными средствами подопечного, представля**ют** (**-ет**) отчет о расходовании средств...*

Возможно ли в первом случае множественное число, а во втором — единственное?
Как правильно?

Answer (score 2):

Нет, невозможно, согласование в числе обязательно:

"Опекун или иное лицо (какое?), осуществляющее управление денежными средствами подопечного,(что делает?) представляет отчет о расходовании средств ..." .

"Или" предполагает выбор одного лица.

Comment: СПАСИБО ЗА ОТВЕТ! В данном случае важно, что осуществлять управление денежными средствами и представлять отчет может как опекун, так и иное лицо, например, усыновитель. Если бы в предложении было написано "опекун или усыновитель", то окончания были бы такие же или все же во множетственном числе? Где можно почитать про предлог "или"?

Comment: Тоже в единственном. Или - разделительный союз. С помо­щью раз­де­ли­тель­ных сою­зов в пред­ло­же­нии сооб­ща­ет­ся о вза­и­мо­ис­клю­ча­ю­щих собы­ти­ях, несов­ме­сти­мых в одно и то же вре­мя явле­ни­ях или после­до­ва­тель­но чере­ду­ю­щих­ся, попе­ре­мен­но сме­ня­ю­щих друг дру­га..  https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/sochinitelnye-soiuzy.html#i-3